# Search for sequence of bytes in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, search

I receive an array like the following:

```
array('b', [71, 69, 84, 32, 47, 97, 115, 115, 101])
```

and I would like to know if a certain sequence of bytes appears in it, e.g. `47 98 113`

What is the quickest and most pythonic way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it first to a list with `.tolist()`, and then if you want to search for exact sequence this could be helpful:

```
a = [71, 69, 84, 32, 47, 97, 115, 115, 101]
b = [47, 98, 113]
def search(what, where):
    if len(what) > len(where):
        return False
    idx = [i for i, x in enumerate(where) if what[0] == x]
    for item in idx:
        if where[item:item+len(what)] == what:
            return True
    return False
search(b,a)
#False
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do

a.find(b)

It will return a -1 if it's not in there otherwise it will return the index number where the beginning of b is found in a

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).